# How to build standalone jar files without including dependencies

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, executable-jar

I am building a solution from the back of my head and also as a java newbie.

I am seeking advice from experts here for my following conundrum:

a) In selenium IDE, I have a project which I shall call it `Login`. Under this
   project's default package, I have three java files, namely     `Chrome.java`,`Firefox.java` and `Credentials.java`.

b) `Credentials.java` is the global file for both `Chrome.java` and `Firefox.java`. Any changes to `Credentials.java` can be made without re-building `CHrome.java` and `Firefox.java`.

c) I created a jar file for `Chrome.java` and `Firefox.java` respectively by selecting each of the java files and the Export it as runnable jar files.

d) The whole operation is such that at any one time, only either `Chrome.jar` or `Firefox.jar` can be executed and will read `Credentials.java`.

d) My issue is when the jar files are built, it includes calling to `Credentials.java`. My goal is to only build standalone jar files for `Chrome.jar` and `Firefox.jar`, so that I can make changes to `Credentials.java` without re-building `Chrome` or `Firefox`.

Hope to have advice on what mistake I have commited and suggestions on how to carry out my intended operation.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't know what is the content in Credentials.java. Hope it is an key value pairs mentioned in java. Better make it to a property file, then you only need to restart the jar file instead of rebuilding.

Comment: Hi Shiriram, actually Chrome.jar (or Firefox.jar) is to test a login page. Credentials.java is basically the file that consist of functionality that will read an excel sheet that contains a list of username and password. When executed, Chrome.jar (or Firefox.jar) will call to Credentials.java, and in turn will feed Chrome.jar (or Firefox.jar) with the username and password. Basically, it's a data driven testing. Thank you.

Comment: By the way, what is the property file that you mentioned ?

Comment: Its just a key value pair. If you are using a java file with functionality without rebuilding is not possible.

Comment: Your advice is that in my case, I have no choice but to rebuild the Chrome.jar (or Firefox.jar) whenever I modify Credentials.java ?